# iOS7 AVCapture captureOutput never gets called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please understand that I cannot upload the whole code here.

I have

```
@interface BcsProcessor : NSObject <AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate> {}
```

and BcsProcessor has `setupCaptureSession` and `captureOutput` method.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray*)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection


- (NSString*)setUpCaptureSession {
    NSError* error = nil;

    AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.captureSession = captureSession;

       AVCaptureDevice* __block device = nil;
    if (self.isFrontCamera) {

        NSArray* devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        [devices enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(AVCaptureDevice *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if (obj.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
                device = obj;
            }
        }];
    } else {
        device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    AVCaptureMetadataOutput* output = [[[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init] autorelease];
    output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes

    dispatch_queue_t outputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.1337labz.featurebuild.metadata", 0);
    [output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:outputQueue];

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

    if ([captureSession canAddInput:input]) {
        [captureSession addInput:input];
    }

    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:output]) {
        [captureSession addOutput:output];
    }

    // setup capture preview layer
    self.previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];

    // run on next event loop pass [captureSession startRunning]
    [captureSession performSelector:@selector(startRunning) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

    return nil;
}
```

So the code above sets up the session and add `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`. and `BcsProcessor` is supposed to receive the captured metadata. but my captureOutput method does not receive any data, or gets called.

I'll appreciate any help or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure your input and output are correctly added to the session. You can check by logging `captureSession.inputs` and `captureSession.outputs`.

Second make sure output.metadataObjectTypes is correctly setup meaning output of `availableMetadataObjectTypes` is not empty. I believe this will be empty if you call it before adding the output.

and finally i don't see you adding the preview layer to the views layer 
try after you init your layer with session...

```
self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. However I do check the input and output adding in the code. Also types are set `output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes` and previewLayer gets set at the end of the code. I see the camera running fine. But it just doesn't pass any data to `captureOutput` method.

Comment: output.availableMetadataObjectTypes does not return an empty array? if so move this line output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes after you add the output to captureSession.

Comment: Thanks zero that fixed the issue. it gets to captureOutput method. :)